# Can't Enable firebasedynamiclinks api for project

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am trying to get the api explorer for the function firebasedynamiclinks.getLinkStats

After logging in for Oauth and executing the request I get the following error message.

> Firebase Dynamic Links API has not been used in project 
>   before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/overview?project=%ProjectId%
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Following the link with the provided %ProjectId% from the original error takes me to a page that gives me the following error:

> The API "firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you
>   don't have permission to access it

It seems strange that I have the ability to generate dynamic links and do so manually just fine. I don't know which project I need to enable the dynamic links api for as I have enabled it for the Google Scripts project that I am using it in.

How can I get access to manually created dynamic link analytics?